# How to force the current script to be used?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, caching

I have an asp.net mvc 3 project that I am developing in Visual Studio 2010. In the `scripts` section I have a library that I wrote. I made a change to the library. However, I notice that the change does not show up when the program is run in the browser. When I look in the debugger of firefox it shows the old version loading. I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, building, closing firefox, ctrl f5 on the page. How can I get the current version of the script to load?

Comment: There are two commonly accepted ways of doing this.  One is to version number the script.. `<script src="mylib_v4.3"></script>`.  The other is nowhere near as good because it kills caching.  `<script src="mylib?version=4.3"></script>`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - I like how you showed both options, I do not like the querystring because it, as you state, kills caching (I like caching). Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two commonly accepted ways of doing this:

**Option 1**
Best option, in my opinion.  Give the script a version number.  Must remember to change the version number with every release

```
<script src="mylib_v4.3.js"></script>.
```

**Option 2**
The other is nowhere near as good because it can kill caching.  Some browsers will re-request the script each invocation.  (I really don't know the which browsers have which behavior.)

```
<script src="mylib.js?version=4.3"></script>
```

**Option 3**
The other option is to keep your scripts in a `version directory`.

Actually, in my PHP code I have

```
<script src="/js/ver##VERSION##/mylib.js"></script>
```

and my php code does a replace of `##VERSION##` with the release version.  This way my build scripts create a directory tree to upload and set paths right.  If you have server side support, this method works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "version parameter" to the script reference :

```
<script src="/scripts/myscript.js?version=0.2"></script>
```

That method has the advantage of also doing the job when the your application is being used by clients, and you want to force their browsers to get the newest version when you update your app.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and disable it.

Comment: Too hammer, need more scalpel.

Comment: billy's version idea would be that : )